# Pandas dataframe to numpy void array

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, record, void

I am using the FMPY module, which is a great tool for simulating FMU's.

For input the module needs a signals array of the form,

```
dtype = [('time', np.double), ('step', np.double), ('pshaft', np.double), ('rpm', np.double)]
signals = np.array([(0.0, 1 ,20, 5000), 
                    (1., 1,25, 5000), 
                    (2., 1,30 , 5000), 
                    (3., 1,35, 5000)],
                    dtype=dtype)
```

The challenge I have is to create such an array from a dataframe where the columns are named 'time', 'step', etc...
I have tried to use the `df.to_record(index=false)` but it gives a different NumPy object type. If I look at `dtype` for the two different objects I get this.

```
signals[0].dtype
Out[7]: dtype([('time', '<f8'), ('step', '<f8'), ('pshaft', '<f8'), ('rpm', '<f8')])

test[0].dtype
Out[8]: dtype((numpy.record, [('time', '<f8'), (' step', '<i8'), (' pshaft', '<i8'), (' rpm', '<i8')]))
```

The question is if there is a way to remove the `numpy.record` from `dtype` and see if that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I cannot see that there was a space in the csv file...... So that was a simple user error.

Answer (score 0):

`to_record` produces a `np.recarray`, a subclass of `ndarray`.  It's just like a structured array, but with added ability to reference fields as attributes.  I think it was an early feature of `numpy` that's largely been replaced by structured arrays (and the compound `dtype`). So `pandas` usage is a bit of a hold over from the past.

```
In [190]: x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)], 'i,i')
In [191]: x
Out[191]: array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [192]: x.dtype
Out[192]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

You can make a recarray from structured array with:

```
In [193]: y = x.view(np.recarray)
In [194]: y
Out[194]: 
rec.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)],
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [195]: y.dtype
Out[195]: dtype((numpy.record, [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')]))
In [196]: y.f0
Out[196]: array([1, 3], dtype=int32)
In [197]: y['f0']
Out[197]: array([1, 3], dtype=int32)
```

There must be a conversion back to `ndarray`, but my hunt-and-peck experimenting isn't finding it.  I'll have to breakdown and read the docs :)

Is FMPY module bothered by the use of `recarray`?  I don't think it makes a difference in most `numpy` code.